# AutoLayout on XCODE 6 vertical UIButtons

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder

[image]I am working with AutoLayout and Size Classes (iPhone portrait only). I have a row of horizontal buttons (I have 4 buttons). I am trying to get them constrainted properly to work on all iPhone portrait sizes.

I have almost done it but the font in each button is smaller across the list. 
Can anyone suggest what constraints to use - I have used trailing / leading edge and equal widths.

[image]

Comment: nobody knows how it is done ? I am banging my head too!!

Comment: Add a screen shot of the issue. Or view lecture 8 on AutoLayout it was a big help with me I now have no issues when doing layouts. https://itunesu.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/LZDirectory.woa/ra/directory/courses/961180099/feed

Comment: The screen shot is above, with the menu buttons..

Comment: It's not showing up. I clicked edit on you message and the link I get for the image as http://i.stack.imgur.com/EU4ya.png. When I go to that page it is just blank and it says EU4ya.png 1x1 pixels

Comment: Ok thanks for that information... If you are a auto layout pro - then I have simply got 4 buttons snug aligned - no spaces between them across the VC width and I need them to be the same on all iPhones. no need for landscape just portrait only.

Comment: Which font are you using? How much text? Size of the buttons? Do you have any magic numbers in the constraints? Is it ok if the text wraps? Are using the preview option in storyboard?

Comment: Yup I using preview option. I am using an 12pt font open sans. The buttons are 100 long , overall the VC is 400 long, so 4 sit in snug.. I just want all the the text is too small to wrap. I also have an image in the button. I have tred to add my image again.

Comment: How are you adding the image? Dose it work correctly with out the image?

Comment: i am adding the small image - via interface builder. The image will never change and nor will its text. I have not tried without the image in the UIButton